# Ui button not adding to SkScene

Tags: swift, button, uibutton, skscene

i am trying to create menu's for my game but my Ui buttons are not adding to the scene, can anybody see what I'm doing wrong here? I know the problem is obvious and I'm just missing it lol. AM i adding them to the scene wrong? Or is there something i forgot to define

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

var nextLevelButton = UIButton ()

var previousLevelButton = UIButton ()

var easyText = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "RzLsEasyText.png")
var easyButtonActive = true
var easyButton = UIButton()

var mediumText = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "RzLsMediumText.png")
var mediumButtonActive = false
var mediumButton = UIButton()

var hardText = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "RzLsHardText.png")
var hardButtonActive = false
var hardButton = UIButton()

var nightmareText = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "RzLsNightmareText.png")
var nightmareButtonActive = false
var nightmareButton = UIButton()

class LevelSelect: SKScene {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    self.scene?.size = CGSize(width: 1136, height: 640 )

    easyText.position = CGPointMake(980.865, 394)
    easyText.zPosition = 6
    easyButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(974, 240, 100, 64))
    easyButton.addTarget(self, action: "EasyButtonActive", 
    forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    mediumText.position = CGPointMake(985.603, 338)
    mediumText.zPosition = 5
    mediumButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(974, 240, 178, 64))
    mediumButton.addTarget(self, action: "MediumButtonActive", 
    forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    hardText.position = CGPointMake(981.833, 292)
    hardText.zPosition = 5
    hardButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(974, 240, 105, 56))
    hardButton.addTarget(self, action: "HardButtonActive", 
    forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    nightmareText.position = CGPointMake(984.116, 237)
    nightmareText.zPosition = 5

    goBackButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(137.214, 570, 183, 91))
    goBackButton.addTarget(self, action: "GoBack", forControlEvents: 
    UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    previousLevelButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(468.358, 513, 
    62.173, 89))
    previousLevelButton.addTarget(self, action: "MissionDown", 
    forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    nextLevelButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(667.928, 515.508, 600, 
    600))
    nextLevelButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    nextLevelButton.addTarget(self, action: "MissionUp", 
    forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    self.addChild(levelSelectBackground)
    self.addChild(easyText)
    self.addChild(mediumText)
    self.addChild(hardText)
    self.addChild(nightmareText)
    self.addChild(proceedLabel)
    self.addChild(survivalText)
    self.addChild(challangeText)
    self.addChild(LevelScenePreview)
    self.addChild(levelNumber)

    self.view!.addSubview(survivalButton)
    self.view!.addSubview(challangeButton)
    self.view!.addSubview(proceedButton)
    self.view!.addSubview(goBackButton)
    self.view!.addSubview(goBackButton)
    self.view!.addSubview(easyButton)
    self.view!.addSubview(mediumButton)
    self.view!.addSubview(hardButton)
    self.view!.addSubview(nextLevelButton)
    self.view!.addSubview(previousLevelButton)
        }
```

Comment: have you tried messing around with the zPositions?

Comment: @sicvayne Ui buttons don't have a z position only SkNodes do

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you should not use `UIButton`s or any view in `UIKit` in an `SKView`. They just don't fit in well. They use a different coordinate space from the sprite nodes and they are not a part of the node tree. They still work when the scene is `paused`... It's just a mess.

You should create `SKSpriteNode`s as buttons instead. Create button textures and put them on `SKSpriteNode`s. Override the `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` methods to detect taps. If you have a lot of buttons, you should add an `SKSpriteNode` subclass.

I have written a subclass for you:

```
class ButtonNode: SKSpriteNode {
    override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    var onClick: (() -> Void)?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        onClick?()
    }
}
```